# calculus on finding the volume

Tags: calculus

## Find the volume defined by the following:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1$$ and $$x^2+y^2\leq\frac{(z^2)}{3}$$

Can roughly draw the picture but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realize that the first equation is redundant (just adds the limits) as the second space is always in the first sphere. Now calculate the volume enclosed by second cone

> It can be dissected into small discs of width $dz$ and radius $z/\sqrt{3}$ , calculate volume of this and integrate for $z \epsilon [-1,1] $.

Comment: can you write it out?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the graph of $z = \sqrt{3}.\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Similarly you can draw if for the negative $z$'s.

Since the volume has identical 2 parts, (one part for positive $z$'s, and one for negative $z$'s), finding the volume for only positive $z$'s is enough.

From the graph, you can see that the volume is bounded below by $z = \sqrt{3}.\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and bounded above by $ z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.

Thus when you form the triple integrand, you first find the intersection points of these 2 curves, that is to find a circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. Then you can form your integral by

$\int_{-r}^r \int_{-r}^r \int_{\sqrt{3}.\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} 1.dz.dy.dz$

[image]

EDIT: It is easy to see $r^2 = \frac{3}{4}$